# Linkedin new developer program Companies API impact

Tags: linkedin-api

In my application , I use the following APIs of the companies API,

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/id={id}`

and

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?event-type=status-update`

With the new API program, do I need to change my existing application ? I find the description on the linkedin developer website regarding the same as not comprehensive enough. If I need to continue with the app, do I  really need to get into a partnership program with linkedin or can I continue like I do currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recently contacted the LinkedIn Support regarding the changes.

So first endpoint will be available to you without getting into PartnerShip program. The following endpoints are the only ones that will remain available for use:

```
Profile API — /v1/people/~ 
Share API — /v1/people/~/shares 
Companies API — /v1/companies/{id}
```

The second Endpoint will require Partner Ship program with LinkedIn you can [apply here](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs)

But it will not involve code changes because they will give privileged access to your App. At the time of applying for partnership program they will ask for LINKEDIN_APP_KEY and LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET. They will provide access to these KEY and SECRET.

Comment: One thing that is not clear though is how their API will respond to any requests from Apps that have not been approved by LinkedIn.
For instance, if  I were to query the people API requesting for the basic profile, email address and full profile, would the call fail with a 403 or would they respond with a 200 OK but not return the full profile data?

Comment: They will return 403 Forbidden for the calls which need PartnerShip with LinkedIn. In short if you have not applied for the Program and you are using any call other than the three mentioned it will get blocked..

Comment: @planet260 Thanks, that makes sense. However their people API can be queried asking for both emailaddress and r_fullprofile, where only the r_fullprofile requires approval. So this would also result in a 403 Response?